# OpenCart categories are not showing up

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

The categories have:

1. The "top" option marked already
2. They're assigned to a store
3. They're assigned to a manufacturer

And they're still not being shown. I don't think this is a code issue as it was working just fine with the *default products/categories* and I haven't touched the code yet.

I've researched a lot, but people always say that marking the "Top" option should solve the issue.

Please take a look into the below screenshots.

http://postimg.org/image/yv6p186kf/ 
http://postimg.org/image/wcl00jku7/ 
postimg.org/image/pbx07rj27

Thanks

Edit:

I'm using OpenCart v1.5.6

Edit 2:

It is a parent category.
For those who are still researching this, please read my answer.

Comment: Hi, this question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring OpenCart and not programming. I'd check out OpenCart's support resources

Comment: Answered by myself. Thank you!

Comment: I do not understand Your question and even to Your answer for it... Could You, please, be more specific as it is highly possible You have just misunderstood something...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be an OpenCart bug.
Here is what I've done to fix the issue:

Instead of leaving the "Parent" field as blank, try to type a invalid name in the field so it will show the  **-- None --**  option, select it and click on save. It solved the problem in my case.
Please see the screen shot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWPBY.png

Comment: I am having same issue, Do you have any fix for Opencart 2.1.0.1? I tried your solution but it didn't work

Comment: @Piyush unfortunately I don't. If I were you, I would avoid opencart at all costs. I ended up not putting it into production.

Comment: @Renann thank you for your response, actually in my case It was issue with megamenu Extension, I modified the extension for new category from admin and it is showing now. :)

Comment: I very much doubt this is an actual OpenCart bug, it's more likely your host is using some sort of database cache and making that change cleared it.

Answer (score 4):

Do the following steps:

1. Open and edit your category:
2. In tab Data:
3. Find and Check:

   Top: Display in the top menu bar. Only works for the top parent
       categories.

Answer (score 0):

I was not getting the child categories in the form field so I did this.

1. Create the category without parent
2. Add this category to the products that you want.
3. Now edit the category and add the parent to it.

Answer (score 0):

The component is written to return just 5 top results, the issue arises after there is a categories overload

to Fix the issue goto file

/admin/controller/catalog/category.php

```
function autocomplete()
{
$json = array();
if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name']))
    {
    $this->load->model('catalog/category');
    $filter_data = array(
        'filter_name' => $this->request->get['filter_name'],
        'sort' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'start' => 0,
        'limit' => 5
    );
    $results = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategories($filter_data);
    foreach($results as $result)
        {
        $json[] = array(
            'category_id' => $result['category_id'],
            'name' => strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))
        );
        }
    }

$sort_order = array();
foreach($json as $key => $value)
    {
    $sort_order[$key] = $value['name'];
    }

array_multisort($sort_order, SORT_ASC, $json);
$this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
$this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

and change limit from 5 to a higher number, preferably 20 in

```
 $filter_data = array(
        'filter_name' => $this->request->get['filter_name'],
        'sort' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'start' => 0,
        'limit' => 20
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue I ran into.  When you are in the admin area and trying  to select the category that your product belongs to... Make sure you fully click. I dont have a mouse, so if you have a mouse or trackball this may not address your issue. **My Asus Laptop finger pad allows me to lightly tap or fully click the pad to navigate**.  I had to make sure I clicked my category choices. If I only tapped the pad lightly it pretended to make a selection and the category would not register.  So my issue was probably related to a javascript/hardware quirk.
Wasted an hour with that one.... LOL.

Hope this helps someone else. I am using Opencart version 3.0.3.8

The powers that be at stack exchange may not have the same hardware as me or some of us. Please dont flag this post because you don't understand this post. This will help someone else. These people think they know everything. And probably filter out some good answers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).